# Jsoup Elements maxes at 20 entries

Tags: java, jsoup

the size of my Jsoup Elements seems to be maxed at size 20, no matter what I do.
The purpose is to:

1. Pull the the specified page
2. Select the elements I am interested in (timestamps and texts atm)
3. Combine the selected elements in a new list and print.

But somehow only the first 20 entries will be included. (compare output on console with actual page)

Can someone give me any hint on where I am lacking the deeper understanding?

Thank you very much and best wishes,

kw

---

Console output:

```
22:59
Mein lieber Arbeitskollege hat mich nach Feierabend noch im Studio besucht...
23:02
Und???
23:04
Ich sag nur Personalküche! :D
23:05
Fühl dich gehighfived! ✋:D
10:30
Haha ich hab eben beim REWE einer Frau mit 2 kleinen Kindern im Wagen 5 Tüten Sticker      geschenkt die ich an der Kasse bekommen hab. Die werden sich jetzt den ganzen Tag über das letzte Päckchen streiten. Ich bin so ein teuflisches Genie! 
09:04
Ihr Dorfis könnt ja doch ganz schön gut Party machen
09:55
...und wir wissen das Kühe nicht Lila sind!
00:13
Mein Bett ist viel zu groß um allein drin zu liegen..
00:15
Meins auch
00:16
Wir sind wie die Arschlöcher, die allein mit ihren dicken Autos rumfahren ohne Fahrgemeinschaften zu gründen.
00:20
Bettgemeinschaft?
```

Code:

```
    import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
    import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
    import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
    import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

    import java.io.IOException;

    public class SmsGetter 
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
        {
            String url = "http://www.smsvongesternnacht.de";

            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(30000).get();
            Elements timestamps = doc.select(".sms-tag");
            Elements texts = doc.select(".sms-bubble"); 
            Elements sms = new Elements(400);

            for(int i=0; i<timestamps.size(); i+=2) 
            {
                sms.add(i, timestamps.get(i/2));
                sms.add(i+1, texts.get(i/2));
            }

            for (Element entries:sms) 
            {   
                System.out.format(" %s", entries.text());   
                System.out.println();
            }   
        }
    }
```

Edit: Inserted missing line.

Comment: Could you try `getElementBy` methods instead?

Comment: @vikingsteve: I tried, with the exact same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have selected your elements by the sms-participant class.  Having two selects from the document is causing you to write that weird for loop where you are assuming sms-tag and sms-bubble are the same size.  That being said I looked at the page and there are only twenty sms-participant entries shown.